# Rounding Decimals in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have the value 13.395 in a field.
I want display the value in a query as the rounded value 13.40

Currently using code  ROUND(CAST(price AS decimal(30, 2)), 2) AS price but this is displaying as 13.39
How can this be resolved and why isn't it rounding correctly ?

Edit: Yes - the price field is FLOAT.
If I change to ROUND(CAST(price AS float(10)), 2) AS price this seems to be now bringing back expected value, but not showing trailing zero's on decimal places.

2nd Edit

Code below gives to 2 decimal places and is now rounding  13.395 correctly, but seemingly not on another product at 9.315 (price remains at 9.31 when it should be 9.32).

```
SELECT product, cast(ROUND(CAST(price AS float(10)), 2) as decimal(10,2)) AS price, price as originalprice FROM  dbo.TableFunction('customernumber')
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe the value is really 13.394444444444449.

Comment: Are you, perhaps, using a `float`?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7b62873acb2383bb8076424cfd8be945

Comment: Please [edit] to include the table/field schema and the query/method you used that shows 13.395

Comment: Yes using FLOAT ! That explains it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are using a `float` to store the value. This can be reproed with the below:

```sql
SELECT d,f,r,
       ROUND(V.d,2) AS dr,
       ROUND(V.f,2) AS fr,
       ROUND(V.r,2) AS vr
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(decimal(5,3),13.395),CONVERT(float,13.395),CONVERT(real,13.395)))V(d,f,r);
```

Note that `fr` has a value of `13.39`.

The simple answer is stop storing values as a `float` unless you are happy with such rounding issues. `float` is not a precise value. If, however, you `CONVERT` the value to an appropriate `decimal` scale and size first (so a scale of 3), you don't suffer the problem:

```sql
SELECT ROUND(CONVERT(decimal(5,3),V.f),2) fr2
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(decimal(5,3),13.395),CONVERT(float,13.395),CONVERT(real,13.395)))V(d,f,r);
```

The reason you get the wrong answer is because when you `CONVERT` the value to a `decimal(30,2)` you've already lost the accuracy, as `CONVERT(decimal(30,2),V.f)` returns `13.39`.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=546679a4f0f1fe45f538d845cb043abe)

Comment: Yes, exactly, the field is FLOAT.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the query I am using, is there anyway to MOD this and treat the float field as an actual value for rounding. 9.315 is still 9.31 - very frustrating!!

Comment: From my answer, @Emma *"The simple answer is stop storing values as a `float` unless you are happy with such rounding issues. float is not a precise value."* If you're using a `float`, then you are happy with this. If you're not, stop using `float`.

Comment: Then use an appropriate scale for your `decimal`, @Emma .

Comment: Inserting into a temp table as decimal then selecting the round from that seems to work.